# jenkins logstash-plugin unable to post to elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, logstash, jenkins-plugins

I've installed the logstash-plugin for jenkins and configured it to use the indexer as elastic search.

While executing the jobs I see the following error:

```
16:56:12 [logstash-plugin]: Failed to send log data to ELASTICSEARCH:http://localhost:9200.
16:56:12 [logstash-plugin]: No Further logs will be sent to http://localhost:9200.
16:56:12 java.io.IOException: HTTP error code: 200
16:56:12 URI: http://localhost:9200/logstash-jenkins
16:56:12 RESPONSE: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type:     application/json; charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 21] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 21,Chunked: false]}}
16:56:12 {"acknowledged":true}
16:56:12    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.persistence.ElasticSearchDao.push(ElasticSearchDao.java:113)
16:56:12    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.LogstashWriter.write(LogstashWriter.java:147)
16:56:12    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.LogstashWriter.write(LogstashWriter.java:85)
16:56:12    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.LogstashOutputStream.eol(LogstashOutputStream.java:58)
16:56:12    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.eol(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:60)
16:56:12    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.write(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:56)
16:56:12    at hudson.console.LineTransformationOutputStream.write(LineTransformationOutputStream.java:74)
16:56:12    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
16:56:12    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
16:56:12    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
16:56:12    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
16:56:12    at     java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
16:56:12    at java.io.PrintStream.newLine(PrintStream.java:546)
16:56:12    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:807)
16:56:12    at hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause.print(Cause.java:426)
16:56:12    at     hudson.model.StreamBuildListener.started(StreamBuildListener.java:75)
16:56:12    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1723)
16:56:12    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
16:56:12    at     hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
16:56:12    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Would appreciate any clues on how I can fix this error.

Thanks
- Prateek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Jenkins plugin you need to define elasticsearch url that contains [yourindex]/[yourtype] as follows:
http://localhost:9200/yourindex/yourtype
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi sir, I am trying to send logs straight to Elasticsearch. My elastic is created by the elasticsearch service of aws, I can't find what is the port used in order to configure well the url in the jenkins logstash plugin. Also for the index, should I put the one I want to be created in my els ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Logstash to feed logs into Elasticsearch?  Despite being called 'Logstash Plugin' the Jenkins Logstash plugin doesn't support this.  I found that when I tried to send logs straight to Elasticsearch the plugin worked fine but when I tried to go through Logstash I got the same error as you.

There's currently a pull request in the Jenkins Logstash github to fix this bug (https://github.com/jenkinsci/logstash-plugin/pull/22), but as the plugin hasn't been active for 10 months (at time of writing) I don't have much hope.

If you want to send logs straight to Elasticsearch, you need to configure Elasticsearch to listen to remote connections.  Set the following in your elasticsearch.yml:

network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 7590

Then set the Elasticsearch url in Jenkins to http://:7590/

Hope that helps!