# Jenkins Logstash plugin doesn't send data to Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, logstash, jenkins-plugins

I want to use Jenkins-Logstash plugin to send Jenkins logs to Logstash.

This is how I configured Logstash plugin in Jenkins:

[jenkins-logstash-plugin configuration][1]   [1]:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsIgY.png

I assume in logstash.conf I have to use HTTP plugin in input section:

```
input {
  http {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 31311
  }
}
```

But in Jenkins build logs I can see the error:

```
> [logstash-plugin]: Failed to send log data to
> ELASTICSEARCH:http://host_name:31311. [logstash-plugin]: No Further
> logs will be sent to http://host_name:31311.
> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> host_name:31311 [/host_name] failed: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)  at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
>   at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
> ... 
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> (Connection refused)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
> Method)   at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
```

And the error is gone when I change port number in Jenkins config to Elasticsearch port `9200` instead of `31311`. But in this case data is written directly to Elasticsearch.

How can I set Jenkins to send build logs to Logstash?

**Update**:
I am able to send and get logs in Logstash now, everything works good. But in Jenkins console I can see the error when sending logs to Logstash, is it acceptable?

```
20:54:11 [logstash-plugin]: Failed to send log data to ELASTICSEARCH:host_name:31311.
20:54:11 [logstash-plugin]: No Further logs will be sent to host_name:31311.
20:54:11 java.io.IOException: HTTP error code: 200
20:54:11 URI: host_name:31311/jenkins-qa/type
20:54:11 RESPONSE: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: text/plain, Content-Length: 2] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/plain,Content-Length: 2,Chunked: false]}}
20:54:11 ok
20:54:11    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.persistence.ElasticSearchDao.push(ElasticSearchDao.java:113)
20:54:11    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.LogstashWriter.write(LogstashWriter.java:147)
20:54:11    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.LogstashWriter.writeBuildLog(LogstashWriter.java:116)
20:54:11    at jenkins.plugins.logstash.LogstashNotifier.perform(LogstashNotifier.java:63)
20:54:11    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:720)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:665)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1753)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
20:54:11    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
20:54:11 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use a username and password and key?

Comment: @VonC Thanks. Everything is working now but there is an error message displayed in Jenkins console, is it Ok? Though there is no such error displayed when sending logs to Elasticsearch.(I updated the question with console error info)

Comment: OK I have added an answer addressing that second error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the OP, the first issue was a credential one (username, password, key)

The second error message ("`No Further logs will be sent to...` ") is [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36319816/6309), and means that:

- the url has to be defined in the [JENKINS Logstash Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logstash+Plugin),
- you can try and compile (and manually installed the `.hpi` file) the plugin yourself, since a bug regarding that exception has just been fixed two days ago: [PR 22](https://github.com/jenkinsci/logstash-plugin/pull/22); see [commit 5078fcc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/logstash-plugin/commit/5078fccf16817608308d3d4e67314d59bdabd624).

Comment: Btw, the logs appear in Logstash as one line of text - all logs records are concatenated. Is it possible to get logs in standard multi-line format?

Comment: @jack_017 That I don't know. Maybe this is a configuration issue.